# Stored procedures, return different number of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I wrote a stored procedure but it doesn't work as I need

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE get_info 
@id int = NULL,
@lang nvarchar(15) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SELECT id,
   CASE @lang
    WHEN 'ru' THEN text_ru
    WHEN 'en' THEN text_en
    ELSE (text_en, text_ru)
   END
 FROM task_text
 WHERE (@id IS NULL OR id = @id);
END
```

It doesn't work because case can't return 2 values.

My perfect stored procedure should work like this:

```
exec get_info --> full table id, text_ru, text_en
exec get_info @id = 1 --> specific id, text_ru, text_en
exec get_info @lang = 'ru' --> full id, text_ru
exec get_info @id = 1, @lang = 'ru'--> specific id, text_ru, @lang
```

Comment: Why not always return the same number of columns and just ignore the language you don't need? The way to return a different number of columns (which I don't recommend because it complicates things) Is to use a second select and use an IF statement to determine which select to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by writing the procedure like this way

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE get_info 
    @id int = NULL,
    @lang nvarchar(15) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @lang = 'ru'
BEGIN
   SELECT id,text_ru
   FROM task_text
   WHERE (@id IS NULL OR id = @id);
END
IF @lang = 'en'
BEGIN
   SELECT id,text_en
   FROM task_text
   WHERE (@id IS NULL OR id = @id);
END
IF @lang IS NULL
BEGIN
   SELECT id,text_ru,text_ru
   FROM task_text
   WHERE (@id IS NULL OR id = @id);
END
END
```